# extract the first character

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have for exemple "My String" i want to extract the first character .

```
String *_initialeStr = self.carte.Titre ; 
originalCarte.Init = memmove(_initialeStr , _initialeStr+1,length(_initialeStr));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSString has characterAtIndex: method where you can pass 0 as index...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`characterAtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex%3a) from `NSString` class.

```
- (unichar)characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

Use as below .

```
NSString *temp = @"Hello world";
unichar myCharacter  = [temp characterAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't even look like Objective-C.

Having a property named `Init` is quite confusing and what is `String`?

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
NSString *initialString = self.carte.titre;
originalCarte.initialLetter = [initialString characterAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This outputs the first character of myString:

```
    NSString *myString = @"The text I want to access.";
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[myString length]];

    for ( i = 0; i < [myString length]; i++ )
            [myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithChar:[myString characterAtIndex:i]]];

NSLog( @"First character: %c", [[myArray objectAtIndex:0] charValue] );
```